# How can I understand which version my Mosquitto Broker uses of MQTT?

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I'm a beginner in MQTT, and I'm trying to use Eclipse Mosquitto's broker. I know it has a support for MQTT v5.0 but I can't figure out which version I use while publishing/receiving messages. I want to use MQTT 5.0.

How can I understand which version my Mosquitto Broker uses of MQTT?

Comment: One question at a time, also asking for software recommendations is explicitly off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks, I've edited my question.

Comment: Also cross posting the same question to multiple locations (e.g. the mosquitto mailing list) just duplicates effort from community, please only post to one place at once, if you don't get an answer then you can repost, but understand that most people are volunteers so don't expect instant answers especially at weekends.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the protocol is used is dependent on 2 things

1. What versions of the protocol the broker supports.
2. What versions of the protocol the client supports.

As well as the client supporting MQTT v5, most also need to be configured to use that version since clients need to be backward compatible with older broker